# Add a Relationship filter to NSPredicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK and Xcode 4.5.2. Deployment target is 4.3.

I'm using Core Data to access this entity:

[image]

I want to filter shops but I don't know how to do it (it's my first Core Data project).

I know that I have to use `NSFetchRequest` with a `NSPredicate` or a `NSExpression`.

I write this if statement to show you what I'm trying to do:

```
if ((shop.acceptRate >= filterCriteria.acceptRate) &&
    (shop.categoryId == filterCriteria.shopCategoryId) &&
    ([shop.productsId indexOfObject:filterCriteria.productCategoryId] != NSNotFound) &&
    ([latestLocation distanceFromLocation:shop.shopLocation] <= (filterCriteria.distance * 1000)))
{
    [ ... ]
}
```

**How can I do that using `NSFetchRequest` with a `NSPredicate` or a `NSExpression`?**

I think is something like this:

```
NSPredicate* predicate =
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"acceptRate >= %@ AND categoryId = %@", filterCriteria.acceptRate, filterCriteria.shopCategoryId];
```

But I don't know how to write products Relationship on a `NSPredicate`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, something like this should work:

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"acceptRate >= %@ AND categoryId = %@ AND %@ IN products", filterCriteria.acceptRate, filterCriteria.shopCategoryId, filterCriteria.product];
```

Where `filterCriteria.product` is an NSManagedObject instance of type `Product`